# Implement Retry mechanism using Mono.retry() within Spring WebFlux Reactive code

Tags: rest, java-8, yaml, spring-webflux

Am using Java 8 and Spring WebFlux to call an external REST based server which also has a backup server.

Currently, if there's a failure when calling the server, it hits the backup server with no retry mechanism:

```
public class ServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    MyRestClient myRestClient;

    @Autowired
    MyRestClient myRestClientBackup;

    public Mono<ResponseOutput> getResponseOutput(ResponseInput responseInput) {
        return Mono.just(responseInput)
            .flatMap(input -> {
                Mono<ResponseOutput> mono = myRestClient.post(input)
                    .doOnSuccess(responseOutput -> {
                        log.info("Successfully got responseOutput={}", responseOutput);
                    });
                return mono;
            })
            .onErrorResume(e -> {
                log.warn("Call to server failed, falling back to backup server...");
                Mono<ResponseOutput> mono = myRestClientBackup.post(responseInput)
                        .doOnSuccess(responseOutput ->
                                log.info("Successfully got backup responseOutput={}", responseOutput));
                return mono;
            });

    }
}
```

---

Am trying to implement a retry mechanism where upon setting a `numRetries` property in `application.yml` set to a specific number, this should happen:

e.g. if the `numRetries = 2`

Use `MyRestClient` to hit the original server twice (since `numRetries = 2`) and if that fails to hit the backup server.

---

This has the `numRetries` configuration property set to a static value:

`application.yml`:

```
client:
   numRetries: 2;
```

---

Class that loads config properties from `application.yml` file:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public ClientConfig {

    @Value("${client.numRetries:0}")
    private int numRetries;

    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

---

`ClientConfig` is used by `MyRestClient`:

```
public class MyRestClient {

    @Autowired 
    ClientConfig   config;

    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

---

Upon obtaining the value for the `numRetries` from `MyRestClient` how can I change the original implementation inside `ServiceImpl.getResponseOutput()` to use `numRetries` to hit the original server before calling the backup server? As you can see that this is all originally done using Java 8 lambda and streams...

Found this annotation `@Retryable(value = RestClientException.class)` but don't know how to specify the `else if numRetries is used to call the backup server` (pseudocode)?

Is there a lambda function to denote the `numRetries` to use within the:

```
return Mono.just(responseInput)
            .flatMap(input -> {
```

How to do use the `Mono.retry()` operator?

Also, the version of `reactor` in this code seems to have deprecated the `Mono.retry().retryBackOff()` method?

How could I use the value referencing `numRetries` (which would be an `int`) to dictate to keep retrying (upon failure) and then when `numRetries` is exceeded up `.onErrorResume()` to call the other backup server?

Comment: Mono has a retry operator. Did you try using that? https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#retry-long-

Comment: @MartinTarjányi - Yes, I did actually find the `retry` operator and was going to edit my post accordingly (which I already now did) - thanks for mentioning it as well! If you re-read my revised post, that would be great!

Comment: `mono.retry(numRetries)` should do the job

Comment: Thanks Martin, can you please provide a code sample demonstrating this?

Comment: Added answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `retry(int)` operator from `Mono` as below:

```java
Mono.just(responseInput)
    .flatMap(input -> myRestClient.post(input)
        .retry(getNumRetries()) // this is the important part
        .doOnSuccess(responseOutput -> log.info("Successfully got responseOutput={}", responseOutput)))
    .onErrorResume(e -> {
        log.warn("Call to server failed, falling back to backup server...");
        return myRestClientBackup.post(responseInput)
            .doOnSuccess(responseOutput -> log.info("Successfully got backup responseOutput={}", responseOutput));
    });
```